# Вопросы со строчной буквы

Tags: обсуждение

Заметил, что много вопросов на SO заданы с ошибками. Есть вопросы как и с достаточно серьёзными ошибками, которые, конечно же, быстро модерируются, так и, по мнению большинства, с несерьезными погрешностями.

К примеру, ко вторым относятся вопросы, начинающиеся со строчной буквы и не имеющих знаков пунктуации. К примеру [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487471/wordpress-выборка-записи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487471/wordpress-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8).

Проблема в том, что исправляя такие ошибки я столкнулся с комментарием от модератора, который настаивал на том, что не следует исправлять такие вопросы. Кроме того, он отклонял мои изменения.

Хотел бы поднять данную проблему среди остальных участником и решить, что делать с такими сообщениями. Ведь так или иначе, начинать предложение со строчной буквы - ошибка. Да и такие вопросы элементарно выглядет некрасиво.

Comment: А `щаблоны` Вас не смутили в ответе по упомянутой теме?

Answer (score 8):

Соглашусь, это плохо выглядит.

Но:

- На самом SO (имею ввиду локализацию) куча подобных ошибок.
- Исправлять ВСЁ - это жуть, ведь не только в каждом первом вопросе есть ошибки, но и в ответах тоже.
- Далеко не все тут имеют степень магистра грамматики русского языка.

Поэтому у исправления должны быть чуть более серьёзные мотивы, нежели "косвенный падеж страдательного залога повелительного наклонения искажает нарратив".

---

Исправляйте "**жи-ши пиши через ы**", а старт с неверного размера буквы пущай живёт.
Однако, если есть возможность исправлять другие, более серьёзные ошибки, будет греховным не исправить всё, что можешь.

Answer (score 4):

Лично моя позиция: правки очень мелкие и улучшающие, но улучшающие мало, практически ничтожно.

У очень мелких улучшающих правок есть три минуса которые мне с ходу приходят в голову:

1. Засоряют очередь проверок.
2. Открывают вообще всем возможность для очень быстрого фарма репутации "на заглавных буквах", так количество правок в день если я правильно помню, ничем
   не ограничено.
3. Засоряют главную.

С пунктом 3) как ранее здесь обсуждалось несколько раз, принято решение жить, пока не придет новая версия движка.

Недостатки пунктов 1). и 2). не распространяются на юзеров которые имеют 2к+ репутации, имеют возможность править без ограничений и не получают репутацию за правки.

Пункт 1) на мой взгляд не очень важен, так как очередь проверок итак пустует.
А вот пункт 2). может быть реальной проблемой если ограничения на количество предложенных правок нету (могу ошибаться, может и есть?).

Если просто хотите сделать мир лучше, нафармите 2к репутации и правьте на здоровье, врядли кто-то будет откатывать.

Если не хотите ждать 2к репутации, старайтесь сделать правки более значительными: в голову приходит явная орфография, форматирование неотформатированного кода, вынос кода со сторонних источников вроде jsfiddle. Вопросов где такие правки нужны - много.

Comment: Мне казалось, что не больше 20 правок в сутки (когда речь о +2), но могу ошибаться. Давно уже не получал за это репу, а без репы и ограничений нет.

Comment: Засоряют главную — не такая уж проблема. С репутацией у Vadizar тоже вроде бы всё в порядке, он её на ответах может нафармить сколько нужно. )